# Stop static mesh from moving with camera

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am trying to move the camera in the character class viewport.  Whenever I hit 'play', the static mesh has repositioned itself almost as if its parented to the camera.  So if I move the camera along the z axis, the mesh will not move but when I hit play it will have replaced itself to the relative position it was underneath the camera before I moved the camera component.

In other words, I am trying to unlink the movement between the two components.

I'm not sure how to disable this.

Here is my code for the character class.

```
// Copyright 1998-2018 Epic Games, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

#include "ZombieShooterCharacter.h"
#include "ZombieShooterProjectile.h"
#include "Animation/AnimInstance.h"
#include "Camera/CameraComponent.h"
#include "Components/CapsuleComponent.h"
#include "Components/InputComponent.h"
#include "GameFramework/InputSettings.h"
#include "HeadMountedDisplayFunctionLibrary.h"
#include "Kismet/GameplayStatics.h"
#include "MotionControllerComponent.h"
#include "XRMotionControllerBase.h" // for FXRMotionControllerBase::RightHandSourceId

DEFINE_LOG_CATEGORY_STATIC(LogFPChar, Warning, All);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// AZombieShooterCharacter

AZombieShooterCharacter::AZombieShooterCharacter()
{
    // Set size for collision capsule
    GetCapsuleComponent()->InitCapsuleSize(55.f, 96.0f);

    // set our turn rates for input
    BaseTurnRate = 45.f;
    BaseLookUpRate = 45.f;

    // Create a CameraComponent 
    FirstPersonCameraComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("FirstPersonCamera"));
    FirstPersonCameraComponent->SetupAttachment(GetCapsuleComponent());
    FirstPersonCameraComponent->RelativeLocation = FVector(-39.56f, 1.75f, 64.f); // Position the camera
    FirstPersonCameraComponent->bUsePawnControlRotation = true;

    // Create a mesh component that will be used when being viewed from a '1st person' view (when controlling this pawn)
    Mesh1P = CreateDefaultSubobject<USkeletalMeshComponent>(TEXT("CharacterMesh1P"));
    Mesh1P->SetOnlyOwnerSee(true);
    Mesh1P->SetupAttachment(FirstPersonCameraComponent);
    Mesh1P->SetupAttachment(GetCapsuleComponent());
    Mesh1P->bCastDynamicShadow = false;
    Mesh1P->CastShadow = false;
    Mesh1P->RelativeRotation = FRotator(1.9f, -19.19f, 5.2f);
    Mesh1P->RelativeLocation = FVector(-0.5f, -4.4f, -155.7f);

    // Create a gun mesh component
    FP_Gun = CreateDefaultSubobject<USkeletalMeshComponent>(TEXT("FP_Gun"));
    FP_Gun->SetOnlyOwnerSee(true);          // only the owning player will see this mesh
    FP_Gun->bCastDynamicShadow = false;
    FP_Gun->CastShadow = false;
    // FP_Gun->SetupAttachment(Mesh1P, TEXT("GripPoint"));
    FP_Gun->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);

    FP_MuzzleLocation = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("MuzzleLocation"));
    FP_MuzzleLocation->SetupAttachment(FP_Gun);
    FP_MuzzleLocation->SetRelativeLocation(FVector(0.2f, 48.4f, -10.6f));

    // Default offset from the character location for projectiles to spawn
    GunOffset = FVector(100.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);

    // Note: The ProjectileClass and the skeletal mesh/anim blueprints for Mesh1P, FP_Gun, and VR_Gun 
    // are set in the derived blueprint asset named MyCharacter to avoid direct content references in C++.
}

void AZombieShooterCharacter::BeginPlay()
{
    // Call the base class  
    Super::BeginPlay();

    //Attach gun mesh component to Skeleton, doing it here because the skeleton is not yet created in the constructor
    FP_Gun->AttachToComponent(Mesh1P, FAttachmentTransformRules(EAttachmentRule::SnapToTarget, true), TEXT("GripPoint"));
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Input

void AZombieShooterCharacter::SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    // set up gameplay key bindings
    check(PlayerInputComponent);

    // Bind jump events
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Jump", IE_Pressed, this, &ACharacter::Jump);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Jump", IE_Released, this, &ACharacter::StopJumping);

    // Bind fire event
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Fire", IE_Pressed, this, &AZombieShooterCharacter::OnFire);


    // Bind movement events
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveForward", this, &AZombieShooterCharacter::MoveForward);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveRight", this, &AZombieShooterCharacter::MoveRight);

    // We have 2 versions of the rotation bindings to handle different kinds of devices differently
    // "turn" handles devices that provide an absolute delta, such as a mouse.
    // "turnrate" is for devices that we choose to treat as a rate of change, such as an analog joystick
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("Turn", this, &APawn::AddControllerYawInput);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("TurnRate", this, &AZombieShooterCharacter::TurnAtRate);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("LookUp", this, &APawn::AddControllerPitchInput);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("LookUpRate", this, &AZombieShooterCharacter::LookUpAtRate);
}

void AZombieShooterCharacter::OnFire()
{
    // try and fire a projectile
    if (ProjectileClass != NULL)
    {
        UWorld* const World = GetWorld();
        if (World != NULL)
        {

            const FRotator SpawnRotation = GetControlRotation();
            // MuzzleOffset is in camera space, so transform it to world space before offsetting from the character location to find the final muzzle position
            const FVector SpawnLocation = ((FP_MuzzleLocation != nullptr) ? FP_MuzzleLocation->GetComponentLocation() : GetActorLocation()) + SpawnRotation.RotateVector(GunOffset);

            //Set Spawn Collision Handling Override
            FActorSpawnParameters ActorSpawnParams;
            ActorSpawnParams.SpawnCollisionHandlingOverride = ESpawnActorCollisionHandlingMethod::AdjustIfPossibleButDontSpawnIfColliding;

            // spawn the projectile at the muzzle
            World->SpawnActor<AZombieShooterProjectile>(ProjectileClass, SpawnLocation, SpawnRotation, ActorSpawnParams);

        }
    }

    // try and play the sound if specified
    if (FireSound != NULL)
    {
        UGameplayStatics::PlaySoundAtLocation(this, FireSound, GetActorLocation());
    }

    // try and play a firing animation if specified
    if (FireAnimation != NULL)
    {
        // Get the animation object for the arms mesh
        UAnimInstance* AnimInstance = Mesh1P->GetAnimInstance();
        if (AnimInstance != NULL)
        {
            AnimInstance->Montage_Play(FireAnimation, 1.f);
        }
    }
}



//Commenting this section out to be consistent with FPS BP template.
//This allows the user to turn without using the right virtual joystick

//void AZombieShooterCharacter::TouchUpdate(const ETouchIndex::Type FingerIndex, const FVector Location)
//{
//  if ((TouchItem.bIsPressed == true) && (TouchItem.FingerIndex == FingerIndex))
//  {
//      if (TouchItem.bIsPressed)
//      {
//          if (GetWorld() != nullptr)
//          {
//              UGameViewportClient* ViewportClient = GetWorld()->GetGameViewport();
//              if (ViewportClient != nullptr)
//              {
//                  FVector MoveDelta = Location - TouchItem.Location;
//                  FVector2D ScreenSize;
//                  ViewportClient->GetViewportSize(ScreenSize);
//                  FVector2D ScaledDelta = FVector2D(MoveDelta.X, MoveDelta.Y) / ScreenSize;
//                  if (FMath::Abs(ScaledDelta.X) >= 4.0 / ScreenSize.X)
//                  {
//                      TouchItem.bMoved = true;
//                      float Value = ScaledDelta.X * BaseTurnRate;
//                      AddControllerYawInput(Value);
//                  }
//                  if (FMath::Abs(ScaledDelta.Y) >= 4.0 / ScreenSize.Y)
//                  {
//                      TouchItem.bMoved = true;
//                      float Value = ScaledDelta.Y * BaseTurnRate;
//                      AddControllerPitchInput(Value);
//                  }
//                  TouchItem.Location = Location;
//              }
//              TouchItem.Location = Location;
//          }
//      }
//  }
//}

void AZombieShooterCharacter::MoveForward(float Value)
{
    if (Value != 0.0f)
    {
        // add movement in that direction
        AddMovementInput(GetActorForwardVector(), Value);
    }
}

void AZombieShooterCharacter::MoveRight(float Value)
{
    if (Value != 0.0f)
    {
        // add movement in that direction
        AddMovementInput(GetActorRightVector(), Value);
    }
}

void AZombieShooterCharacter::TurnAtRate(float Rate)
{
    // calculate delta for this frame from the rate information
    AddControllerYawInput(Rate * BaseTurnRate * GetWorld()->GetDeltaSeconds());
}

void AZombieShooterCharacter::LookUpAtRate(float Rate)
{
    // calculate delta for this frame from the rate information
    AddControllerPitchInput(Rate * BaseLookUpRate * GetWorld()->GetDeltaSeconds());
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any luck with the answer i posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attaching the mesh to the camera. If you don't want to parent the two then remove this line:

`Mesh1P->SetupAttachment(FirstPersonCameraComponent)`

You should call SetupAttachment only once for each component